# What is the product of the reaction of 2-bromo-1-fluoro-4-nitrobenzene with sodium methanethiolate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halides

In the reaction depicted below shouldn't $\ce{Br}$ be replaced by $\ce{SCH3-}$ ion as $\ce{Br-}$ is a good leaving group and the $\ce{C-F}$ bond is quite strong due to back bonding of 2pπ-2pπ orbitals?

[image: 2-bromo-1-fluoro-4-nitrobenzene with sodium methanethiolate]

Comment: What is the rate limiting step in this reaction? What is the structure of the intermediate? This should help you think about what happens.

Comment: I'd suggest looking up *nucleophilic aromatic substitution* in a textbook; the issues you are asking about should be described in any decent text. In particular, any decent text should be able to explain why (1) the 2- and 4-positions relative to the electron-withdrawing group are activated towards substitution and (2) the order of reactivity is F > Cl > Br > I.